# when i add google analytics, occur classcastException

Tags: android, google-analytics, classcastexception

now i'm adding google analytics in my app.

i'm all have done following google analytics homepages.
(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#manifest)

but after I add Tracker code in my MainActivity, i'm occur ClassCastException when i running my app.

please give me a answer.

i'm already searching google and stack overflow.

behind is my code.

ApplicationTrackers.java

```js
package com.zla.android;

import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Application;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
import com.zla.android.R;

public class ApplicationTrackers extends Application {

 private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXXXXXX-2";

 public enum TrackerName {
  APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
  GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
  ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
 }
 HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();
 
 synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
  if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {   
   GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
   Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
     : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
     : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
   mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);     
  }
  return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
 }
}
```

global_tracker.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
 
 <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->
    <screenName name="com.zla.android.MainActivity">
        MainActivity
    </screenName>
    
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXXX-2</string>
</resources>
```

ecommerce_tracker.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>
 <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXXX-2</string>    
</resources>
```

MainActivity.java

```js
package com.zla.android;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  
  
  /* add google analytics --------------------------------------------- */
  Tracker t = ((ApplicationTrackers)getApplication()).getTracker(ApplicationTrackers.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
  t.setScreenName("MainActivity");
  t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
  /* ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
```

androidManifest.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zla.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    
    <!-- about google analytics -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:largeHeap="true"  >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <activity
            android:name="com.zla.android.SearchBrandActivity"
            android:label="search page" />
        
        <activity
            android:name="com.zla.android.SearchFrameActivity"
            android:label="search page" />
        
        <activity
            android:name="com.zla.android.ListActivity"
            android:label="list page"
            android:parentActivityName="com.zla.android.MainActivity" >
        </activity>
        
        <activity
            android:name="com.zla.android.ListActivity_WishList"
            android:label="list page"
            android:parentActivityName="com.zla.android.MainActivity" >
        </activity>
        
        <activity
            android:name="com.zla.android.DetailActivity"
            android:label="detail page"
            android:parentActivityName="com.zla.android.ListActivity" />
        
        <!-- about google analytics -->
        <meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
                
        <activity
            android:name="com.zla.android.ApplicationTrackers"
            android:label="google analytics" />
        
    </application>

</manifest>
```

error LogCat

```js
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zla.android/com.zla.android.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.zla.android.ApplicationTrackers
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:997)
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.zla.android.ApplicationTrackers
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322):  at com.zla.android.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:67)
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5177)
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
04-05 03:27:42.498: E/AndroidRuntime(22322):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: you again =)  see at com.zla.android.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java) line 67

Comment: The exception occurs in line 67 of MainActivity which is not included in your code snippet. Either post the rest of the code or analyze line 67 yourself. :)

Comment: in you case using getApplication()).getTracker(ApplicationTrackers.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER); must be called from fragment

Answer (score 2):

You are not using your `com.zla.android.ApplicationTrackers` as application implementation. You need to add `"name"` attribute to the application element in your AndroidManifest.xml with the class name extending android.app.Application.

```
<application
    ...
    android:name="com.zla.android.ApplicationTrackers">
    ...
```

Without the name attribute Android has no way to know what class implements the application and will instantiate the default `android.app.Application`. When you later try to cast it to your custom application class the cast fails as you are trying to cast `android.app.Application` to `com.zla.android.ApplicationTrackers`.

Comment: this is the answer

Answer (score 0):

`Tracker t = getTracker(ApplicationTrackers.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);` try this

Comment: i'm add "Tracker t = getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);" but error occur in "getTracker"(occur red line) ,,,

Comment: i'm not understand your word. is it right to change my code to "Tracker t = getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);" ? i'm replace my code to "Tracker t = getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);" but it also do not work. and replace another code to "Tracker t = getTracker(ApplicationTrackers.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);" it's same not work. please full code. thank for reply!

Comment: yes you need to change your code to Tracker t = getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

Comment: yes I have same error after change code. "Tracker t = getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);" hmmmmmmm. the error occur "getTracker"(red line). the message is "The method getTracker(ApplicationTrackers.TrackerName) is undefined for the type MainActivity"

Comment: rebuild project. Your classes conflict is in    import com.zla.android.R;

Comment: thank for helping! but when i replace code to "Tracker t = getTracker(ApplicationTrackers.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);" it doesn't work. the error message is "The method getTracker(ApplicationTrackers.TrackerName) is undefined for the type MainActivity" i'm more hard working to find this problem.